# Deserialize object based on value type in property

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

**TL;DR**: Is there an easy way in json.net to inspect the type of a property and create an instance based on that?

I have the following two objects in JSON, these are relation objects in the [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org):

```
{ "data": { "type": "Test", "id": "1" } }
```

and

```
{ "data": [{ "type": "Test", "id": "1" }, { "type": "Test", "id": "2" }]}
```

Using json.net, I want to serialize these objects to either the class ToOneRelation, or ToManyRelation. The classes look like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(RelationshipConverter))]
abstract class Relation
{
    [JsonProperty("meta")]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Meta { get; set; }
}
class ToOneRelation : Relation
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
class ToManyRelation : Relation
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<object> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Generally I only know that I want to have a Relation, so I would do the following:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Relation>(json);
```

In order to instantiate the correct object, I need a custom converter, where I check the type of the "data" property. When the type is an array, I use the ToManyRelation, otherwise I use the ToOneRelation.

Currently I created a custom converter that will walk over all properties and deserialize them.

```
object toOneData = null;
List<object> toManyRelationData = null;

Dictionary<string, object> meta = null;

reader.Read();
while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName)
{
    string propertyName = reader.Value.ToString();
    reader.Read();
    if (string.Equals(propertyName, "data", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            toOneData = serializer.Deserialize<object>(reader);
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            toManyRelationData = serializer.Deserialize<List<object>>(reader);
        }
    }
    else if (string.Equals(propertyName, "meta", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        meta = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(reader);
    }
    else
    {
        reader.Skip();
    }
    reader.Read();
}
```

Although this works, I have the problem that this code isn't really maintainable. As soon as an extra property is introduced to the Relation object (or the other objects) I need to modify this code to reflect those changes.

So my question is is, is there a better way to inspect a property to identify which type to create and than use `serializer.Populate` method to do the rest?
(The CustomCreationConverter doesn't work, because it can't inspect the properties before creating the object is created...)

(Note, a working example can be found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dP43KC))

Comment: Make your class `Relation` have a `List<object> Data` in all cases, and use `SingleOrArrayConverter<Relation>` from [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18997172/3744182).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, when it is just the Data property that is different in both cases, it would be a good solution, but what if either the ToOneRelation or the ToManyRelation gets more properties that the other doesn't have?

Comment: Then you want either [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307752/deserializing-polymorphic-json-classes-without-type-information-using-json-net) or [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538).

Comment: Actually this solution doesn't really work. When using a List for both ToOne and ToMany, it is more difficult to serialize an empty relationship correctly. the ToOne should be serialized as `null`, but the ToMany should be serialized as `[]`. This adds complexity to the users of the Data property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8031283/3586533) I came up with the following solution:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var json = JToken.Load(reader);
    object relationship = CreateObject(json);
    if (relationship != null)
    {
        serializer.Populate(json.CreateReader(), relationship);
    }
    return relationship;
}
private object CreateObject(JToken token)
{
    if (token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (token["data"] == null)
    {
        return new ToOneRelation();
    }

    switch (token["data"].Type)
    {
        case JTokenType.Null:
        case JTokenType.Object:
            return new ToOneRelation();
        case JTokenType.Array:
            return new ToManyRelation();
        default:
            throw new Exception("Incorrect json.");
    }
}
```